# BLE Python with GUI on OSX

Tags: serial, bluetooth, python, wireless

Has anyone connected BLE devices with Python + GUI on OSX? I've looked into a few libraries (most are old), but one that has the most success if Adafruit's BlueFruit library. However, this library works poorly with GUI's since it requires use of the main event loop (which GUI's usually use). After doing a bunch of Google searches, I couldn't find any good examples of using a GUI with Python + BLE. There seems to be no good BLE libraries for Python either.

Specifically looking for help integrating BLE with Kivy, but other GUI toolkit examples should be fine.

Also trying to gauge interest in this to see if I can do development to solve this (if it really is a problem).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Arduino but rather desktop GUI software for OSX.  Perhaps you can solve your difficulty using multiple threads (or programs) and pipes or mailboxes between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still searching for a lib check out:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE

Its specifically made for BLE communication on OS X or Linux by wrapping the corebluetooth and its Linux equivalent bluez in a python lib. Windows is not supported at this moment.

Unfortunately there is no documentation to it. You will have to read the examples and search for specific functions in the lib manually.